# Redirecting entire domain using .htacsess except some URL's

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an entire domain to a new domain except for some URL's. The 3rd and the first redirect condition is working but not the second one. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file-download-search` is getting redirected to the new domain and I want this not to redirect. Any help is appreciated.

```
    # Redirect users from domain1.com to https://www.domain2.com
    # Except the download center and the pdf files
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)domain1\.com$ [NC]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/file-download-search
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/files/([^/.]+\.pdf)$
      RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you clear your browser cache or try with other browser ?

Comment: I did. still not working

Comment: For a test, change the line with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/file-download-search [NC]` (without ^ and with [NC])

Comment: Just in case the link used for the test would not be really accurate ... :-/

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is looking for answers this is what worked for me.

````
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)domain1\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\ /file-download-search [NC]
 https://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]```
````